# Как вернуть ссылку на массив, если метод его возвращающий еще работает?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Предположим есть метод со множеством этапов, работа которого может затянуться на долгое время. Хотелось бы, что бы была возможность по WebSocket'ам получать от него какие-то сведения. Я подумал, что главное - это вернуть ссылку на массив с логами, чтобы периодически опрашивать его на наличие новых строк. 
Примерный упрощенный код, в итоге получаю пустой массив. Где ошибся?

```
public class SimpleWorker {
    public List<String> doWork() {
        List<String> logs = new ArrayList<>();
        // делаем что-то, что даст нам результат выполнения в виде строки
        // метод может работать очень долго
        // периодически закидывая результат в logs
        logs.add("simpleLog1");
        // делаем что-то, что даст нам результат выполнения в виде строки
        logs.add("simpleLog2");
        return logs;
    }
}


public class CallableTest implements Callable<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> call() throws Exception {
        SimpleWorker simpleWorker = new SimpleWorker();
        return simpleWorker.doWork();
    }
}

public class SimpleMessageService {
    public void execute() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        CallableTest test = new CallableTest();
        Future<List<String>> future = executorService.submit(test);

        try {
            for (String str : future.get()) {
                // получаю пустую строку
                // даже c Thread.sleep()
                sendSocketMessage(str);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в том, что метод future.get(), это блокирующий метод. Т.е. он застрянет на вызове future.get() и не вернет ссылку на коллекцию, пока не будет выполнен метод call() в  CallableTest.
Для того, чтобы увидеть состояние вашей коллекции в любой момент времени, её нужно создавать не внутри метода doWork() класса SimpleWorker, а внутри метода execute() класса SimpleMessageService, и потом прокидывать внутрь CallableTest, а затем в SimpleWorker. Таким образом коллекция будет доступна в самом SimpleMessageService.
Попробуйте лучше разбить независимые задачи друг от друга на небольшие таски Callable, каждая из которых возвращала бы результат в виде нужной вам строки.